# Calculate total number of items received when item is received on more than one shipment

Tags: sql, sum, ms-access-2007

I have a set of tables in Access 2007 that I need to get to display the total number of items received.  We order items against a job using the job number as a common reference (like an ID).

Each job has multiple items required.  Most items have multiple shipments we receive.  Each shipment is given a unique receiving ticket number, so they need to be entered individually and totaled.

I have:

- tblJobItems :*JobNumber, Item, QtyNeeded*
- tblReceived :*JobNumber, Item, QtyRecvd, RTNumber*  (RT = Receiving Ticket)
- tblJobs     : *JobNumber, JobQty*   (and more, but not relevant to this issue)

(JobQty is not always the same as the item's QtyNeeded. The job is like a run of a certain model of computer, the job qty is how many of that model. Items are sometimes 1:1, like a case or power supply, but can be 2:1 or 3:1 like having multiple hard drives.)

I have a query that works fine to show the number of items placed on order, but we want to expand it (or combine with other queries) to show the total number of items received per the job number on the same line.  Eventually I'll use this number to change the status and other functions.

```
SELECT tblJobItems.JobNumber, tblJobItems.Item, tblJobItems.QTYNeeded, tblJobItems.PartStatus, First(tblJobs.BDT) AS FirstOfBDT, First(DateAdd("ww",-2,[BDT])) AS DueBy
FROM tblJobItems INNER JOIN tblJobs ON tblJobItems.JobNumber = tblJobs.JobNumber
GROUP BY tblJobItems.JobNumber, tblJobItems.Item, tblJobItems.QTYNeeded, tblJobItems.PartStatus;
```

This shows me in a listbox the items ordered and how many, the JobNumber is stored as `([Tempvars]![JobNum])`, and the listbox only shows the records that match the JubNumber.  (the tempvar is global, so it can be used in a query if that helps anyone)

I'm not opposed to having this go through two or three queries to get to the answer.

Comment: I did find a solution for this using the IIf function in a query along with SUM.  As a bonus, it places a 0 in every line that had no values before so it doesn't look like the answer is missing.

Comment: I just didn't know that I could do a calculation on a calculation in the same query... I though I'd have to run one query and then another to do so.

Comment: Thanks HansUp, still learning about forums... never used them for so many years and just discovering how useful they can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the key piece needed in my query's SQL was:

```
Sum(tblReceived.ReceivedQTY) AS SumOfReceivedQTY, IIf(IsNull([SumofReceivedQTY]),0,[SumofReceivedQTY]) AS RECQTY
```

This sums up the quantity and also creates a new column in the query with the totals.